# When calling a mixin in Jade, what's the difference between "+" and mixin keyword?

Tags: node.js, keyword, pug, mixins, templating

The [docmentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade?source=cr#a14) tells us to call a mixin by prepending the keyword `mixin` to the actual mixin.

```
.bar
    mixin foo(arguments)
```

But on different places I saw people calling a mixin by prepending a plus (+) sign, like:

```
.bar
    +foo(arguments)
```

Could someone please explain the difference since the documentation does not seem to show it. I tried both examples and both seemed to work.

Is `+` just a shorthand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it appears so. If you look at `lib/lexer.js` in the `Call mixin` section, you can see that terms beginning with a `+` get tokenized with type `call`. Later in `lib/parser.js` the `call` token causes `parseCall` to create a new mixin invocation node.

Furthermore the commit was made with with the comment:

> Added preliminary mixin block support and the new + mixin invocation
>   syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I found out additionally is that it does not seem to be possible to use ```blocks``` of mixins when you call a mixin with the ```mixin``` keyword while it works with the ```+``` keyword. (tested with CodeKit)